# Active Admin Scope with rails 4.1

Tags: activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am getting this error in Active Admin with rails 4.1

Showing ../bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `call' for ClassList::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xa9f44bc

Extracted source (around line #1)

1 insert_tag renderer_for(:index)

Below is my code that I am using

ActiveAdmin.register ClassList  do
 #....
 scope :upcoming_classes
 #....
end

and in Model

class ClassList < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :upcoming_classes, where('class_date > ?', Date.today)
end

Please anyone help me in fixing this error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your scope using a `proc`.

```
class ClassList < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :upcoming_classes, proc { where('class_date > ?', Date.today) }
end
```

Rails 4+ expects scopes to be wrapped with a callable object, which is usually defined as a `proc`. See the [Active Record Query Interface: Scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) documentation; there they use the `-> { }` proc syntax.